# Initializing a boolean to use in every api call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a service shown below

```
public interface SomeService{

@GetMapping("/someapi")
public Object getData();
}
```

i have impl class shown below

```
public class ServiceImpl{

private boolen isSomeCondition;

public Object getData(){
callSomeMethod();
if(isSomeCondition)
//do something
else
//do some other
}
```

```
public void callSomeMethod(){
if(someCondition)
//do something
else
//set isSomeCondition to true
isSomeCondition=true;
}
```

i want this isSomeCondition to be set to false initially for every call to the "/someapi" and later to be changed when callSomeMethod is executed. whatever i have above doesn't seem to work as global variable isSomeCondition is stateless bean.
what could be alternatives to this?

Comment: @oh-god-spiders does it initialize the boolean to false every time the api is called?

Answer (score 0):

If you require state, then introduce state. Create a stateful object for each request:

```
public class ServiceImpl{
  public Object getData(){
    final DataGetter getter = new DataGetter();
    return getter.getData();
  }

  static class DataGetter {
    private boolen isSomeCondition;

    public Object getData(){
      callSomeMethod();
      if(isSomeCondition) {
        //do something
      } else {
        //do some other
      }
    }

    public void callSomeMethod(){
      if(someCondition) {
        //do something
      } else {
        //set isSomeCondition to true
        isSomeCondition=true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since you are using Spring, changing the bean scope might be an option too:

```
@RequestScope
public class ServiceImpl {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i cannot make the class DataGetter static.

Comment: @unknown why not? (But if you can't, then don't do it. Just be aware that it will hold a reference to the enclosing class)

Comment: the classes are already existing, just need this logic in place.

Comment: @unknown I don't understand. I introduced the class `DataGetter`, it is not present in your original question. If you already have a different class with that name, choose a different name.

Comment: i have already have all the classes in my original code(in the question, i have changed names of the classes). i cannot modify the classes, i just want to change the code.

Comment: @unknown then try a different bean scope (if adding an annotation does not count as "modifying the class"). Otherwise, if your code is not doing what you want it to do, how do you expect to fix it without changing it?

Comment: here's my question again, without modifying my classes(annotations, names etc ) where do i place the isSomeCondition variable so that it will be initialized to false for every api call?

Comment: @unknown you place it in a stateful class that you instantiate on every call. Sorry if this is not the answer you are looking for. Maybe you could hack around it with a `ThreadLocal`, but that can cause many other problems (especially for devs new to Java)

Comment: i'm thinking of this way, declare and initialize the isSomeCondition to false inside the getData method and pass it to the callSomeMethod and change it's value based on condition. it should work right?

Comment: @unknown `callSomeMethod` must then return the new value. Or you are migrating to an array/dataholder/AtomicBoolean. All of these sound like "changing the class" to me, so I'm not sure why that would be okay, but the proposed solution with a stateful class would not be?

Comment: i was thinking of pass by reference but that doesn't work in java.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. Instead of having isSomeCondition as global variable have it as local variable and pass it to the method.

```
public class ServiceImpl{

   public Object getData(){
   private boolen isSomeCondition;
   isSomeCondition = callSomeMethod(isSomeCondition);
   if(isSomeCondition)
   //do something
   else
  //do some other
  }
```

Here based on your condition you can set it and return.

```
 public boolean callSomeMethod(){
    if(someCondition)
    //do something
    else
   //set isSomeCondition to true
    isSomeCondition=true;
   return isSomeCondition;
  }
```

Comment: i can't do this because the callSomeMethod doesn't return boolean value in my case.

Comment: @unknown, then you can have the boolean pass by reference by having a wrapper class around it. if you pass the object to callSomeMethod then it would change the original value. but this also would be changing that method signature

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why changing the method's return value is a problem, but adding new parameters is not. The requirements/rules are very inconsistent

Comment: i thought of this, without declaring isSomeCondition, i will just call a new method that will return the boolean based on some condition.

Comment: @knittl i don't think i have any other way, so going to change the return value.